# Code run in Jupyter Lab uses very different GPU RAM than run as a script

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

I am training a 3D siamese network in PyTorch. When I run the code from an iPython (v7.15.0) terminal the GPU RAM usage maxes out at 1739M:

[image]

When I copy the same code into a Jupyter notebook (in Jupyter Lab v2.1.5) the GPU RAM usage is 10209M:

[image]

Jupyter Lab was run from the terminal in the same Python virtual environment.

First, I don't understand why running the script in Jupyter Lab would increase GPU RAM usage by a factor of almost 6.

Second, and related, is there anyway to have Jupyter Lab run in a mode that uses somewhere in the range of 1739M for the GPU RAM?  I love the ability to have all the "documentation" around the code and output.

Python version 3.6.9.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I realized what the difference was when I run the two.

I have two GPUs on the machine a Quadro M2000 that drives the video and the Titan XP.  When I ran JupyterLab on the command line I ran it as `jupyter lab`, but when I ran iPython I ran it as `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 ipython --pylab`. Without the CUDA_VISIBILE_DEVICES it gave me warnings about mis-matched GPUS.   When I ran in the iPython terminal I saw the warnings previously, but I didn't see them when I ran JupyterLab.

So, it is still odd that the RAM usage on the Titan XP would jump to 10G+ of RAM.